# SQL Server 1/Countif

Tags: sql-server, count

Is there an equivalent to 1/countif in SQL Server?

Something like:

```
SELECT ID,1/COUNTIF(ID)
FROM Table
```

...that divides 1 by the number of rows with a certain ID in Table, returning the results in this format:

```
ID  Result
1   0.5
1   0.5 
2   1
3   0.33
3   0.33
3   0.33 etc.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your version is 2005 and newer, you can use `OVER` with the aggregate `COUNT()`:

```
SELECT id
     , 1.0 / COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY id) AS countif_ID
FROM TableX ;
```

You can find more examples in the MSDN site: [`OVER` clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461%28v=sql.90%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks, this is great.

Can it be used for countifs i.e. count based on more than one column?

Comment: Yes, you can have as mnay counts as you want.

Comment: Like this: 

`1.0 / COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY id, col1, col2 etc.) AS countif_ID`?

Comment: Yes, if you want to count how many rows have same `id` and `col1` and `col2`, yes.

Answer (score 1):

No exact equivalent to COUNTIF but it's easily done using standard SQL.
Try something like this (if your table is called "test"):

```
SELECT ID,
       1.0 / (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM test t2 WHERE t2.ID = t1.ID) AS result
FROM   test t1;
```

See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/bfcbb/5

Answer (score 1):

Another variation but I like @ypercube's simple solution best.

```
;WITH x(ID,c) AS (SELECT ID, COUNT(*) FROM dbo.Table GROUP BY ID)
SELECT t.ID, 1.0/x.c
FROM dbo.Table AS t
INNER JOIN x ON t.ID = x.ID;
```